# on click submit button move itsplace

Tags: html, css

I m Using submit button for my form its work fine in all browser except ie7
when an user click on it it moved please suggest me what to do

```
.confirm-button-submit 
{
   width       : 79px;
   font        : bold 12px sans-serif;;
   color       : #000;
   background      : url("../images/confirm-btn.png") 0 -33px no-repeat;
   text-decoration : none;
   margin-top      :0px;
   text-align:center;
   border:0px;
   cursor : pointer;
   height:32px;
   padding     : 8px 0px 12px 0px;
}

.confirm-button-submit:hover 
{
   width       : 79px;
   font        : bold 12px sans-serif;;
   color       : #fff;
   background      : url("../images/confirm-btn.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
   text-decoration : none;
   margin-top      :0px;
   text-align:center;
   border:0px;
   cursor : pointer;
   height:32px;
   padding     : 8px 0px 12px 0px;
}
```

i used this css please tell me what to do

code:

```
<input type="button" value="Show" name="commit" onclick="range_validation(this)" class="confirm-button-submit"/>`
```

Comment: please show more of your html and your js-function "range_validation" (and, if it's possible, an online demo would be very nice)

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "moved"?

Comment: As far as I know whatever it shows on IE 7 its a bug. And other browsers are suppressing it.
With the code given by you its not easy to track what went wrong. So please provide some more information.

Answer (score 0):

The hover class automatically inherits any values not specified, so any repeating attributes you can delete.

Also what do you mean by moved?  If you mean when you hover, the button moves then deleting redundant attributes will help you narrow down which attributes are causing this.

If it's on click, then you will need to show the javascript function "Range_validation" to us to see if it's positioning anything.

Answer (score 0):

First off, your css can be widely reduce:

**IMPROVED CSS:**

```
.confirm-button-submit, .confirm-button-submit:hover
{
   width           : 79px;
   font            : bold 12px sans-serif;;
   color           : #000;
   background      : url("../images/confirm-btn.png") 0 -33px no-repeat;
   text-decoration : none;
   margin-top      : 0;
   text-align      : center;
   border          : 0;
   cursor          : pointer;
   height          : 32px;
   padding         : 8px 0px 12px 0px;
}

.confirm-button-submit:hover
{
   color       : #fff;
   background  : url("../images/confirm-btn.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```

With your css, all seems ok, the problem may be another global style that may be affecting your button, or some other element of your page... do you have a link to view the problem "in action" ?

Answer (score -1):

the submit hover has diferent values for the image than the other submit class, not sure what they are for (never used extra values there) but they look like positioning or margin like values. these could be causing the image to change places when he hovers over it... maybe?